# Current user geographical location

Tags: views, location

I am building a website which on the contact page will have a section to find your local sales representive. I intend to do this by having a content type of sales rep with a location field and creating a view from this content on the contact page.

As an improvement to this i would like it to automatically (if the user allows it) to take the geo location of the user and automatically filter the view by this showing the users nearest sales rep.

Are there any modules in existence which i can use to achieve this? Or am I likely to have to build a custom module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need custom coding to provide the argument to the view, but you could use the following modules for the geolocation functionality:

Feature-rich, server-side solution:
[Smart IP](https://drupal.org/project/smart_ip)

Simpler, ip-based server/client-side solution:
[geoPlugin](https://drupal.org/project/geoplugin)